# Moving wp-content folder to public_html

Tags: uploads, media

I want to move my `wp-content` folder up to `public_html`. I put this in `wp-config.php` (before the "That's all, stop editing!" line):

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/public_html/wp-content' );

define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://bhaktivedantaacademy.com/wp-content' );
```

My site is in a subfolder and so my purpose in doing this is to gett media file URLs without the subfolder name. But it totally didn't work. Now the whole site won't load and I get this: "ERROR: The themes directory is either empty or doesn’t exist. Please check your installation."

Comment: Did you move the folder itself? It's not enough to tell WP to look in a new place, you have to move/copy everything else up too. Keep in mind that users will rarely if ever see the wp-content URLs, and it has zero impact on SEO

Comment: if the site is in a subdirectory, then presumably the media folder is above or parallel to it and thus to the config file. So why are you looking for that folder under it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by using this code instead of the one above:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wp-content');
```